# Php OOP : Parent class values are always null

Tags: php, oop

I have two php classes in two separate files:

File Name : `ld.php`

```
<?php
  class LandDetail_Model{
     public function __construct() {}
     private $id;
     public $pId;
     private $bigha;
     private $katha;

function setId($id) { $this->id = $id; }
function getId() { return $this->id; }
function setPId($pId) { $this->pId = $pId; }
function getPId() { return $this->pId; }
function setBigha($bigha) { $this->bigha = $bigha; }
function getBigha() { return $this->bigha; }
function setKatha($katha) { $this->katha = $katha; }
?>
```

File Name :`Land_Detail.php`

```
<?php
    require_once '../models/ld.php';

    class LandDetail extends LandDetail_Model{
      public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
     }

  public function DoSomething(){
     echo "This is a value from Parent".$this->getPId();
  }
}
?>
```

Now in `SomeFile.php` I am doing something like this.

```
<?php
include 'Land_Detail.php';

$ld = new LandDetail();
$ld->setPId(10001);
$ld->DoSomething();

?>
```

Why `$this->getPId()` is always returning null value? What is wrong with my code here? What is the correct way to extend a class in php from different file?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question.

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/WDk9A), voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: @Siguza It works when I place both the classes in the same file. But it does not work in separate file.

Answer (score 4):

Why you write:

```
$ld->setPId = 10001;
```

Instead of

```
$ld->setPId(10001);
```

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara, also, there's a typo in your code, `$ld = new LandDetai();` should be `$ld = new LandDetail();`.

Comment: Did you try running your code again after these two changes?

Comment: Yes. I've tested it. I just wrongly typed in the question.

Comment: Your code works fine, are you sure you placed all the files in the right locations?

Comment: Ok. I've got the solution. Actually the problem was not in code. I was testing my rest api using Postman. The problem was actually in postman. It does not support POST.